# Access Denied while "creating a Publishing Site Collection in SharePoint 2013" after fresh SP installation

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

**Issue :**
I have been facing an error while creating a Publishing site collection after fresh installation of SharePoint 2013.

**Error:**
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

**Description:**
An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

**Exception:**
[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))]

Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException UnauthorizedAccessException ex) +46  Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetWebMetainfo(String bstrUrl) +521 Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetProperties() +125 Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPPropertyBag..ctor(GetProperties getProperties, UpdateProperties updateProperties) +100 Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Properties() +145 Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.GetLookupListId(SPSite site) +67 Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__a() +162 Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) +193 Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param) +426 Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) +95
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.Initialize(SPFieldCollection fields) +230

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +2579
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProvisionWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, String webTemplateToUse, SPFeatureWebTemplate featureWebTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors) +1085
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors) +582
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PortalProvisioningProvider.CreatePortal(String xmlFile, SPWeb rootWeb) +565

[SPException: Provisioning did not succeed. Details: The site template was not provisioned successfully. Delete this site collection in Central Administration, and then create a new site collection. OriginalException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PortalProvisioningProvider.CreatePortal(String xmlFile, SPWeb rootWeb) +1250
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__0() +42
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.CultureUtility.RunWithCultureScope(CodeToRunWithCultureScope code) +167
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PortalProvisioningProvider.Provision(SPWebProvisioningProperties properties) +421
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProvisionWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, String webTemplateToUse, SPFeatureWebTemplate featureWebTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors) +403
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors) +582
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickerUtil.ApplyWebTemplateAndRedirect(SPSiteAdministration siteAdministration, String strWebTemplate, String strRedirect, Boolean bCreateDefaultGroups, Page page, Boolean bDeleteOnError) +745
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.CreateSitePage.BtnCreateSite_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +2421
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +126
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint

**Reference Image:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jhkk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved after reinstalling the SharePoint 2013 setup.

Thank You in advance :)